# Access a remotely inaccessible webapp through an accessible server

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, web-server, reverse-proxy, ssh-tunnel

I need to access a locally developed `webapp` (port `80`), which is for the time being inside a computer that cannot be accessed remotely: `local machine` (for ex. it's behind a `firewall`).

So, what I thought is using a `remote ssh tunnel` via a `server` which is accessible remotely (via port `80`): `ssh -N -f -R 80:localhost:80 user@server`, but port `80` is used by `apache`.

What I'm trying to achieve is that when I go to `server` on the browser, it's my `webapp` hosted on my `local machine` that shows up.

I will be really interested in a solution to this issue using `apache` using `mod_proxy`, or with a `reverse-proxy` like `nginx` for example.

Comment: Have you tried googling "apache reverse proxy" and following one of the many guides that comes up?  If so, what didnt work?

Comment: First of all, I dont know if it's necessary to configure `apache` (or `nginx`) as a reverse proxy, when I can implement it with an `ssh tunnel`. But even this way, I'm not sure if `apache/nginx` would allow to use `port 80`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I didnt test it as I should.

It's working well right now with:

`ssh -N -f -R 9000:localhost:80 root@server`
Then on any machine when I try to access on the browser to `http://server:9000` it shows the content stored on my `local machine`.

I guess I dont need a `reverse proxy` for that.